# Public link for an invoice

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

When an order is submitted on the Craft Commerce website I'm currently building, an email is automatically sent to the customer. Inside this email is a link to download an invoice for that specific order.

I had accomplished this by putting the following link into my emails

```
<a href="{{ siteUrl }}index.php/admin/actions/commerce/downloads/pdf?number={{ order.number }}">Download your invoice</a>
```

It's not ideal as you could actually download any invoice by changing the order.number, but we fixed that by using a url proxy.

But I realised a few minutes ago that this link is not public and requires a login. Which I don't want.
Is there any way to generate a public link for the invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [simple plugin](https://pluginfactory.io/), that exposed an [anonymous controller action](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions) that mimicked Commerce's `Commerce_DownloadsController`'s `actionPdf()` method.